# Customising item style of a specific item of the series using dataset property instead of series.data Apache Echarts

Tags: angular, echarts, apache-echarts, ngx-echarts

I have a half doughnut chart. When I turn of decal the bottom half becomes visible. I can hide the color of the bottom half as color takes function and I get the item details. But decals color is a string only and same color will be applied to all the decals. But I want to set the decal color as 'none' for the bottom half and for other pie sections as default color.

[image: This I want to achieve using dataset property]

```
const options = {
  dataset: [
    {
      source: [
        {value: 735, name: 'Direct'},
        {value: 580, name: 'Email'},
        {value: 1048, name: 'Search Engine'},
        {value: 484, name: 'Union Ads'},
        {value: 300, name: 'Video Ads'},
        {
          // make an record to fill the bottom 50%
          value: 1048 + 735 + 580 + 484 + 300,
          name: ''
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  aria: {
        enabled: true,
        decal: {
        show: enabled
        }
  }
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Access From',
      type: 'pie',
      emphasis: {
        label: {
          overflow: 'break'
        }
      },
      radius: ['40%', '70%'],

      center: ['50%', '70%'],

      // adjust the start angle
      startAngle: 180,
      itemStyle: {
        color: (param) => {
          if (param.name === '') {
            return 'none';
          }
          if (param.dataIndex > 8) {
            const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(
              16
            );
            return '#' + randomColor;
          } else {
            return halfDoughnutChartColors[param.dataIndex];
          }
        },
        borderRadius: 0,
        borderColor: '#000',
        borderWidth: 0
      },

      label: {
        overflow: 'truncate',
        formatter: (param) => {
          // correct the percentage
          return !!param.name ? `${param.name}: (${param.percent * 2}%)` : '';
        }
      },
      encode: {
        itemName: 'name',
        value: 'value',
        tooltip: 'name'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Matthias Mertens](https://Matthias%20Mertens) answer is almost correct. But now all the pie sections are getting the same symbols. And, we have n items in the source array. So, I think this approach can be followed:
[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=M4ewrgTgxgpgBAXjgbQFBzgbzgNwIYA2YMAXHAOwDMArADRwB2eAtqXAOQAiAlhDFABd2cAL610WXIWJlqADgAM9JqzLsAoszzcCwsROz4ibAIwKALHOUs27AMow80ABZx1DAObcGMPeIyG0myW5taqHACqDNwgDHAAggAmwH4GUsZklApKjDZqAGrciTAgCcmpAekyFDRhtjx8giYVkkbV8jkqtpraBM2i_q1BZGaWdWoOTlCu7l4-_fqVbcFyobnh7FExcUnAC4OBGXBZnXkchcWlu_sGEhgA9PdwWgDW8HhxjSAQiXACpQAzHQEP7OeAAIxAAn-zDg1AUAFI7lVTBY5HAANQ1aiYuGKXEhXEnXGjdFYqg4rEdAmrInZQYYLpqdgSESoAC6AG5UACwAxBNs4B4YAJOPxCMAABQASiwEigsWAAjgxSghDsAE9mJCCMBEChkewoLwoARfAyOI0hBb2AIINwPh4zewbRBwAxEgAlfjWw2JB3MWKJF2GgAO3hDGAw7CcboA7iyMFz5YrlaqJfrQJBYAA6LShyWS7gCGDMejeYoAD1lCAAfHKo3A-AJIHEKzBK4gEEgs9AYDmzZ4BK4ALRwEzIjAAfkkwC1Ors3AAXmwFKJJ3AyNg59qQAQyOmCJrd7rkO3OwiKOzRNyMCJpbe4AqGKAzQOQB5JexDyl6D-HxIzatiq4q6tybIgKGAiCkgmASIkeACHgwAimQaCNnBjYYL2sBkDhMDImySaDE4DpbsiMBMOCZqJGQdrEBah7kVhIFqrqZDCqKoFStKFrYc4IBxmolF4NRMDBoRrKDCh9owMAaHIphWFMhw8RQLAwB6gAYm6zCRlhAgaqGtjhuaG6lqGzjIdw8kNixcAEKJMD7nZ9lwCAOAwBAAIEIJajgnweAvIm9lEVhixYRAeD-mAtnIOw5iIi6HDkEl7LiBusAMCWEBoew8IIsl7CpYV6WoBujxwNFABWsXKsO8BKk4yqOmaG5NRAAjxJ4ZojIofFwMWpZ2IZvWuVhkI_F5nrRdwsVkEoG4YJNxQQAAwnu3xqAAxNkCj6SxK1eQA6kUw4LRu-gbo54LOcx9keV5Pl-Rw9H8ohZluQC3xaNCXlkJKoZOCwNb1kpbmVQqEBWqC8DGX22V4MKS1RkBEBxAAhBjQNRcwOZdHAM4AAYACSYDjLD4zYIgA2TFN4_DWXKgAVHAABMIgItKRObhw7CPixYWNhFjaUQqxT3SxQ3MAAcmc7BdAdWHLGoyxK42_x7tBoZqIrl2SUmqAiJyQA)

```
source = [
  { value: 735, name: 'Direct' },
  { value: 580, name: 'Email' },
  { value: 1048, name: 'Search Engine' },
  { value: 484, name: 'Union Ads' },
  { value: 300, name: 'Video Ads' },
  { value: 735, name: 'Direct1' },
  { value: 580, name: 'Email1' },
  { value: 1048, name: 'Search Engine1' },
  { value: 484, name: 'Union Ads1' },
  { value: 300, name: 'Video Ads1' },
  {
    // make an record to fill the bottom 50%
    value: 1048 + 735 + 580 + 484 + 300 + 1048 + 735 + 580 + 484 + 300,
    name: ''
  }
];
function getDecals() {
  const decalSymbols = [
    'circle',
    'rect',
    'triangle',
    'roundRect',
    'diamond',
    'pin',
    'arrow'
  ];
  const decals = source.map((item, index) => {
    return index === source.length - 1
      ? { symbolSize: 0 }
      : { symbol: decalSymbols[index % 7] };
  });
  console.log('decals', decals);
  return decals;
}
option = {
  dataset: [
    {
      source: source
    }
  ],
  aria: {
    enabled: true,
    decal: {
      decals: getDecals(),
      show: 'enabled'
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Access From',
      type: 'pie',
      emphasis: {
        label: {
          overflow: 'break'
        }
      },
      radius: ['40%', '70%'],

      center: ['50%', '70%'],

      // adjust the start angle
      startAngle: 180,
      itemStyle: {
        borderRadius: 0,
        borderColor: '#000',
        borderWidth: 0
      },

      label: {
        overflow: 'truncate',
        formatter: (param) => {
          // correct the percentage
          return !!param.name ? `${param.name}: (${param.percent * 2}%)` : '';
        }
      },
      encode: {
        itemName: 'name',
        value: 'value',
        tooltip: 'name'
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try and copy the default decal palette and setting the `symbolSize` of the one you want invisable to 0. Here is a quick (incomplete) [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAmBDMWDOApmAFywDaa6ylVsewArgE4DGBpFttSAblgDYN2sAOwBmAKwAaWNCwBbYQHIAIhCYEWYJQF8pNLrwFDSEgBwAGGXMWklAUXlYI_Xfq5Ujg4QEYLAFjNrBWUAZQIsVgALWHtoAHMIaAI3A24-b1JA_2DbWCUAVWgoOABBDDxUj3QvE1gxCytZELsANQgMAmBYcsq9NM8B2gB6YdgnAGsCWCw4DRZgJgxYMG6AMxd-FajpgCNgMFX5WAkLAFIhqgy6v0DYAGpRSQeTyxfsl4arS_QbZSVLjoBgBdAxA9DA9wzJgQLCkVDVWAEOS7fgEDCkMBMIRQjydFgCeE_TCaAR4DhIPSUqTU2lUvAAT3k-34oQgAC9hBYdJDLngosAAO52ZFYVHogGI8GwfroQgwgjk8gGBFcP52UosNh4PCwABiTGA8iUuKoYAZIGUIAgKVN6AI8hAUXwECVqo8_DFBH4RMR6GAPAITDW_CFdl2GiwE0l1WltFlXCYWAwEAYSrISn85xN-RE2d5AzY0DAQY4SlOZxzSjzlYLHlGMwwACs02BttM8LgmG3ZvE0QNO5EwKUEmjSD5LHbYBAS_JQuax9REfslkGAErJ1NK77LxadJgAYWAoaYdgAxI0LCbLiv9wB1DpgKKkCwDfoDT27b2-6oBoMhsN8ixBhoAJEtr0RNZFicQ5S1gAAKEBIgUABKBAAD4lz9BsFiYeY2yfaZLVYZFcHiAhiQ0MBmDgABCWikKTeQADo_lgAB-WAAAMABIkEYhRWJCHRSHgviBJY4iizbAAqWAACYdDOFCuNgOwlAAbkBN8p2RBZOh_DwZwdAA5Fp8j-CDqmuZQbKsjxVmPSAQDsSy3zBShQR0IA) to give you an idea.

Comment: I appreciate your approach. But now all the pie sections are getting the same symbols. And we have n items in the source array. So, I think this approach can be followed: 
[example](https://goo.by/fYyftN)